# is_int('12345') VS filter_var('12345', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)

Tags: php

Что лучше и почему:

```
is_int('12345');
```

или

```
filter_var('12345', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько странный вопрос. Это разные функции и выполняют они разные действия. Достаточно заглянуть в документацию чтобы убедится в этом и понять что их не стоит сравнивать. Это как "что лучше **echo** или **var_dump**?". И то и то выводит что-то на экран.

Опишу, что делает функция [**is_int()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php). 
Она возвращает TRUE в случае если переданный ей аргумент есть INT и FALSE в если не INT.

Функция [**filter_var**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) возвращает отфильтрованное значение. В вашем примере она вернет не **TRUE** а 12345.
Это очень важно понимать и это очень большая разница.

Comment: спасибо, не знал - обычно бегло просматриваю документацию. Больше нравится испытывать функции на деле, чтобы понимать их механизм действия.

Comment: Скачайте по PHP справочник в chm, там всё есть, очень удобная вещь, а у новичком тем более он обязан быть!